# How can I generate the .git *FILE* and how is it (de)constructed?

Tags: git, github

This is ***not a question about the hidden `.git` folder***!!

## My Understanding

I typically use GitHub for most of my Git work. When working with the remote server, I might have my push and fetch configured as such:

```
$git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:<my_org>/<my_repo>.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:<my_org>/<my_repo>.git (push)
```

The question here is specifically about that ***`<my_org>/<my_repo>.git`*** file.

I know that it "contains" all of the machinery required for a repository: the files, the index, hooks, references, etc. I have been "imagining" that it is a hierarchical zip file that is essentially just the entire repository as it would look locally if I were to zip it all up.

## My Questions

1. Is my understanding correct? Is the `<blah>.git` ***file*** just a zip of the repository? How do I generate it?
2. What does git do in order to construct / deconstruct it, each time I either `git init` and `git push` or each time I `git clone`? (Is this really just a zipping and unzipping?)
3. Is there any way to *create* this structure myself? E.g., is [this](https://hub.github.com/hub.1.html) how GitHub does it on their end (more or less)?

   - And can I use that same `git init -g` command or something similar to create a `.git` file.
4. Where is the documentation on this `<blah>.git` file (beyond the link above)?

   - I did search for a little while, but everything on `".git"` turns up the hidden directory, not the file.
5. If I create this `<blah>.git` file on my machine, can others then use my machine as a remote repository?

   - Put another way, how would I create a machine and a file/folder structure to act like a remote repository for someone else?

Comment: Your question seems pretty broad, but if you just want to copy a repository to a new location, all you need to do is copy the `.git` folder and that is all.

Comment: <blah>.git is a directory. It's by default the name of a bare git repository. `git init --bare <blah>.git`

Comment: As @ElpieKay said, it's not a file, it's a directory. The contents of bare repository `foo.git` match the contents of `.git` in non-bare repository `foo`, except that the `config` file has `core.bare` set to `true`. (But the best way to set it up from an existing non-bare clone is to `git clone --bare`, and perhaps set `core.shared` as well.) To use it as a server, your machine must allow some kind of access, whether that's ssh, http, via the `git://` protocol, or whatever.

Comment: Oops, I should have said `core.sharedRepository` (it has been a long time since I set up Git servers).

Comment: Thanks to all of you for the information, but I think you were misunderstanding my point.  At **some point** `<my_repo>.git` ***IS*** a file, not a directory. My link embedded in the question and VonC's answer below may help you to better understand. (There is still much I don't understand, of course, hence my question. But I did understand that this is at some point **also** an archive-like file, and not just a directory structure.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No: `repo.git` it is a folder representing a bare repository (no working tree, just the repo files)

The compression/decompression only occurs for [delta encoding of the pack files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9478566/6309), which are then transmitted during clone/pull/push.

If you want to build only one "zip" file, see [`git bundle`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27861997/6309), which produces a full Git repo as *one* file.

Comment: On bare repo: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sitaramc/git-notes/6ab1eada80d7c7a676cbd94a5d58f556634d794b/concepts-and-tips/bare.notes, https://github.com/sitaramc/git-notes/blob/cb3ac8bcb85f7d11bb45aa89becd90c8b4738bf1/concepts-and-tips/0-terminology.notes